# How to fix "modules are duplicated" in angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor

Throw error was,

> CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules
>   are duplicate

When add `codeBlock` plugin to `defaultPlugins` in ckeditor5

[image]

Comment: Please write code instead of image.

Comment: Information you provided in the question isn't sufficient. Provide you code where you are importing CKEditor modules for example or share project with issue reproducible.